# Installing gem fails with permissions error

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I updated my Mac OS to 10.9 Mavericks yesterday. My current Ruby version shows as

> ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

I got Rails installed on my machine and when I try to install gems I get the following message:

```
Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I am trying all this in my home directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: With my "best engineering practice" hat on I agree with @Stuart Nelson. With my "if you're just learning Ruby or using it for one thing" hat on, solve this problem by using sudo. `sudo gem install eventmachine`. This will bite you if you have a few dozen separate Rails/Ruby projects from multiple sources that you're running... but if it's a simple utility here and there, ehhh...

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Just did the above command and it got installed. I know sudo gives me lots of abilities and hence many users ask to avoid it altogether. However, this is my first time and I want to try my hands on RoR, hence the effort. What should I do to not use 'sudo' every time and get a clean install without having to think of installing any useless things

Comment: I would argue that rvm and rbenv are quite useful, and not useless at all. They are your best option to avoid having to use `sudo` every time, and getting yourself into a versioning nightmare down the road.

Comment: If you're using Rails the Bundler gem should keep the gems for your different apps away from each other. I know people that use almost exclusively that. Just using that - like every Rails tutorial written after... 2011(?) will show you how - may make you happy for maybe even your first year of Rails development. (I didn't start wanting RVM until my first year / 4th or 5th client project)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I was aware of that thread and referred it before creating this one. But all the steps mentioned in it didn't help me. Even now, I was able to install ruby and rails through RVM, but still getting permission error while installing gems. Although `sudo` is coming handy and I can get work done. I would appreciate if could point me to right direction if you think I'm missing something. I'm running all these commands in my home directory as you have edited.

Comment: I installed RVM but I can't run gem install rspec in terminal. What is going on? I get an error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a Ruby version manager, like [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

I can't speak for rbenv, but RVM prepends a Ruby version-specific `bin` to your `PATH` that you have access to, so you don't have to use `sudo` (which is how you could install gems in your current situation, but is highly discouraged).

rbenv similarly prepends to your `$PATH`, but it uses a shim.

Comment: I tried installing rvm but I am getting into permission issues. 
    bash: line 704: /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied

Comment: what do you get when you enter `ls -l ~/.rvm/RELEASE` on the command line? Something is funny with your permissions.

Comment: you would get something like `-rw-r--r--  1 aniruddhabarapatre1  staff  7 Oct 24 19:07 .rvm/RELEASE` if you had access.

Comment: Yes. This is something I'm getting. `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  7 Sep  1 14:37 /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/RELEASE`

Comment: Ah yeah. You installed rvm as root (see how it says 'root' in there), so you don't have access to it. You need to remove the `.rvm` folder with `sudo rm -rf .rvm`, and then install rvm without sudo. It will then be owned by you, and not root.

Comment: I tried above command and I still get following message - `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  7 Sep  1 14:37 /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/RELEASE`

Comment: did the above command successfully remove `.rvm`? Make sure that folder is gone, log out of your terminal, log back in, and then the rvm install command: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Thanks a ton @Stuart. This helped me a lot. I could install rvm with your instructions and now will move ahead. Anything else that I should be careful about?
Although I am still getting permission issues when I'm trying to install gems

Comment: The last step is to use rvm. Type `rvm install ruby`, then make sure it is set to the default. You shouldn't be required to use sudo after that.

Comment: Should I be doing this in my home directory? I have rails and rubyv2 installed on my machine, but installing gems still needs `sudo` to be prepended to it.

Comment: `rvm install ruby`; `rvm use ruby --default`; if you have more questions post a new question or read the documention: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Answer (score 10):

When I had this same error it was because I did not have a Ruby version manager installed, it defaulted to the Ruby version that came shipped with my computer which is owned root.

Since it is a very bad idea to use `sudo` to install gems, I installed RVM with Ruby 2.1.2

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.1.2
```

then made sure that it was being used as the default by running

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.2
```

RVM creates a new location to store your Ruby and gems with your user permissions so you don't have to use `sudo` or get a permissions error. The new gem location is:

```
~/.rvm/gems
```

Then carry on as you were...

```
gem install ....
```

Comment: this worked - note (on osx) for some reason 'ruby --version' command showed old version (2.2.0) even though latest was installed.  'rvm list' will show versions installed and available to be switched to. After switching (rvm use ruby-2.1.2) then 'ruby --version' showed correct (2.1.2) version.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have RVM installed. I got this error because I installed rbenv but did not run `rbenv init` yet.

After I inserted the contents from the command `rbenv init` into .bash_profile, `gem install` works as expected.

I also happened to set `rbenv global <ruby-version>` to a downloaded Ruby version first.

Comment: If [the rbenv install directions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) are followed the initialization code will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just like to say to you all after wasting a good hour or more on trying to install RubyGems... to **rubygems-2.4.5** ***'sudo'*** got me through! 
It works a treat...

Comment: don't do this. it would be better to give access to that directory to the user performing the install or by using rbenv or rvm

Comment: `sudo` can create more problems than it'll solve unless you're very familiar with how the system and Ruby, especially multiple Rubies, work together.