# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-elcapitan, compass

I just updated my Mac to OSX 10.11 El Capitan and some gems didn't remain.

The problem arose when I tried to run installations of different gems... e.g.:

```
> sudo gem install compass
```

Once I execute, I get the error:

```
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted
```

This happens with other gems, as well...

I've run Homebrew and tried to install Ruby again, but nothing is working.

Comment: Write this command in terminal : sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: change the default path to installing gems by  `echo "gem: -n/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.gemrc`

Answer (score 447):

I found the answer on SASS issues: 
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768

Since `OSX el Capitan` there is a new security function that prevents you from modifying system files called Rootless. So you have 2 options:

- If you install gems on `/usr/local/bin` there will be no problem because rootless doesn't affect this path.
- **`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE`**

Comment: To build on what Roy said, [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md#if-usrlocal-does-not-exist) is a link to the homebrew docs on the issue, and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/3n26gt/upgrade_to_el_capitan_with_homebrew_ruby/) is a link from Reddit detailing a proper upgrade; perhaps you could see if trying anything there would help.

Comment: "disable rootless function and install gems after the reboot" did not work for me. However, "sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE" solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This solution witch  `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE` **worked perfect** for me (OS X 10.11.1). Install sass and compass again, was easy with this command. 

Btw it seems to be the most prominent solution for that.
e.g. to find here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768

And in exisiting issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972968/cant-install-gems-on-os-x-el-capitan

Comment: I run gem install on MAC OS from VNC. for some reasons, It returns error ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - . Then the command: sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE work well for me. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33043199/1816277

Comment: doesn't work for me. I got this error While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

Comment: you can make it the default by echo "gem: -n/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.gemrc

Comment: Without sudo: `gem install --user-install GEM`. No permission required, pod will be installed into `~/.gem/`.

Answer (score 11):

You are experiencing this issue because of a new security feature called [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html)

You can disable SIP by following the process mentioned below:

1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and
   holding down Command+R until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window, type in csrutil disable and press Enter.
4. Restart your Mac.

Comment: That's right Abid. Thanks However, the other solution its easier IMO

Comment: Installing gem at **/usr/local/bin** is a cool solution considering **"Roorless"**, I am not sure though but you may experience issues while executing something from **/usr/lib/...** folder e.g. MySQL can cause issues with libmysqlclient.18.dylib I believe Apple will come up with some guideline or solutionas **"Rootless"** will cause issues with developers

Comment: For me, adding "rootless=0" as a boot argument didn't work, however using csrutil did. Thanks!

Comment: Disabling rootless is a bad idea. Don't unless you have a good reason. Needing to install a gem is not a good reason.

Comment: yes, it works fine. Thank u brother.