# gem update/install operation not permitted since el capitan. how to set default path

Tags: rubygems, osx-elcapitan

Does anybody know why **after updating to Mac OS El Capitan** `gem` has started giving errors for `install` or `update` commands?

Example:

```
$ sudo gem update
Password:
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
  Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

For some reason the path has to be set explicitly. Example:

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
Password:
Fetching: sass-3.4.19.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.4.19
Parsing documentation for sass-3.4.19
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.4.19
Done installing documentation for sass after 6 seconds
1 gem installed
```

This is pretty annoying! Is there a way to make `/usr/local/bin` default?

Comment: Recommended reading for those finding this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891965/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeperm-operation-not-permitted?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same problems, found this:

- Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
- Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
- Run the following command in Terminal:
  `csrutil disable`
- Restart

source: https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/

Comment: I did not know anything about OS X El Capitan Rootless. Thank you for the explanation and steps for disabling. I did not like to disable it, but it worked like a charm!

Comment: This is extremely dangerous, and should be accompanied with warnings that this operation disables an important OS X security feature.

Comment: Yeah, @eyelidlessness here's an article recommending keeping it on. I should have provided more background info. 

http://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: There are 4 options when i rebooted. Where was this Utilities menu?

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly answering your question, but since your accepted answer is a little dangerous, I would like to share how I solved the actual issue of not being able to install a gem.

In my case I was having a problem with compass and had the same error, which is what I entered in my search and Google brought me here. I ran

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

But if you are doing a fresh install on a new computer. Make sure that you have **bash** installed. Here is a brief transcript of what I did.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use homebrew, there is another solution you can try in the below commands. This does involve installing the homebrew version of Ruby. This fixed the problem for me, although I'm middling in my knowledge of Unix. So I can't speak to how wise or unwise it is to give yourself ownership of /usr/local. Maybe a Unix expert can chime in here.

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby
```

Source: http://www.hacksparrow.com/os-x-el-capitan-screwed-up-ruby-gems-and-how-to-fix-it.html