# Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, chmod

The folllowing error appears in my logs when i try to upload a file with carrierwave.

```
Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /home/daniel/public/my_app/public/uploads):               app/controllers/admin/file_uploads_controller.rb:21:in `manual'
```

This happens when i execute the following action:

```
def manual
    Product.where(distributor: 'handmatig').map{|c| [c.update(deleted: true)]}

    @file_upload = FileUpload.new(file_upload_params)
    @file_upload.name = "united"

    if @file_upload.save
      flash['notice'] = "Uw bestand is geupload."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

Line 21 is the line that holds `if @file_upload.save`.

I tried using `sudo chmod -R 777 public/uploads/`, but it doesnt appear to help.

What is causing this error and how do i get passed it? I wish i was more familiar with permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891965/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeperm-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: I had this error saving files to a Windows network drive, mounted via CIFS on my Ubuntu server. Adding the `noperm` option to fstab resolved the issue for me. This option means "client does not do permission checks," which effectively makes CarrierWave's chmod a no-op, I think. The security implications of that don't matter in my context, but you should do your own evaluation, `man mount.cifs`.