# Unicorn+Sinatra+Nginx | FATAL error adding listener

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

I have a Sinatra application hosted using Nginx and Unicorn. it went down when I upgraded the operating system (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) on the server, and I was able to bring them all back up except this one, the lone Rack-based application. When I try to launch Unicorn (`unicorn -c unicorn.rb -D`), I get the following error:

```
I, [2017-08-06T15:39:54.426004 #6505]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/tmp/unicorn.wheels-within-wheels.sock
F, [2017-08-06T15:39:54.427777 #6505] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/tmp/unicorn.wheels-within-wheels.sock
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:113:in `unlink': Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - /tmp/unicorn.wheels-within-wheels.sock (Errno::EPERM)
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:113:in `$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:107:in `$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:231:in `li$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in `bl$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in `ea$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:808:in `bi$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:130:in `st$
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed after I performed the following two steps:

1. As described in this Server Fault [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/425691), I changed the group of the application owner, 'deployer', from 'deployer' to 'staff'.
2. I changed the owner of the socket file to `deployer:staff` (`sudo chown deployer:staff /tmp/unicorn.wheels-within-wheels.sock`).

Then I ran `bundle update` to update the gems, and finally Unicorn ran successfully and the application was live again.

Comment: I need to confirm whether both steps were necessary to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following link said that kind of problem is occured upgrading MacOSX to El Capitan. if you can follow the same path, maybe you could resolve the problem.

[ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891965/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeperm-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: I wasn't installing a gem. And while I'm running macOS Sierra, the error occurred while I was ssh'd into the server running Ubuntu 14.04.5, in case that wasn't clear.