# 'pod init' returns: Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

When I try perform `pod init` in my Xcode project directory, it returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    35: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    34: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.2/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    32: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    31: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.2/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    28: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    19: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    17: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    16: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/concurrent_ruby_ext (LoadError)
    46: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.2/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    42: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.2/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    40: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    39: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    36: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    34: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    33: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    31: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    30: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:212:in `try_activate'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `find_by_path'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `find'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `each'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1042:in `block in find_by_path'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
     2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

I have already installed `Homebrew`, `Ruby`, and `Cocoapods` already. I'm running `macOS Catalina 10.15.4` and `Xcode 11.3.1`.

I tried to follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892222) and install cocoapods in `/usr/local/bin` via the following command: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

but I got the same error when installing it: `Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)`

Any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT**

After reinstalling Ruby manager to install Ruby, I'm getting a new error:

```
2: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/hooks (LoadError)
    13: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'
    12: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    11: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    10: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
     9: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
     8: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find'
     7: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `each'
     6: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1037:in `block in find_by_path'
     5: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
     4: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
     3: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
     2: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
     1: from /Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/Users/zorgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted in the comments below, this was resolved by moving the project out of `~/Library` as this is a special system directory on macOS and can trigger the error above. Even so, the recommendation to use a Ruby manager stands as a best practice:

You're having an issue with macOS sandboxing permissions. The easiest fix is not to use the built-in version of Ruby that ships with macOS and instead use a Ruby manager to install Ruby:

1. Install RVM with:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

2. Restart your shell
3. Install Ruby with:

```
rvm install 2.6
```

4. Install cocoapods with this command (and do **not** use `sudo`):

```
gem install cocoapods
```

5. Confirm that the output of `which pod` is something like:

```
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/pod
```

Then retry your `pod init` command.

Here’s a resource that explains why not to use your system's default version of Ruby:

- https://dontusesystemruby.com

There are other managers you can install and use if you prefer:

- https://asdf-vm.com/
- https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Each has its benefits and drawbacks, but after 7 years of professional Ruby development RVM has never done me wrong so it's what I recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I followed every step and Ruby successfully reinstalled. However, I'm still getting a very similar error when I write `pod init`. I've added the error message in my edit above if you'd like to see.

Comment: @Zorgan Thank you for posting the error. Can you tell me what directory you're in when you run `pod init`?

Comment: I was in my Xcode project directory when I ran `pod init`: `/Users/zorgan/library/Autosave Information/app/app`. I also tried running it in  `/Users/zorgan/library/Autosave Information/app/` and got the same error.

Comment: This is a permission error you can `[[ -s /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to end to .bashrc

Comment: What if you move out of `/Users/zorgan/library`? `~/Library` on macOS is a special system directory. Try moving your project somewhere else, like `~/Documents`, then try again.

Comment: YES MOVING THE PROJECT DIRECTORY WORKED - thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that I was within a subdirectory of my project root (a directory that happened to be the same name as my project root, thus I didn't notice).

So be sure you're in the correct directory for your project that uses cocoapods.

Comment: This was my problem, happened to me at least twice now because I had a terminal open in a repo folder, deleted the folder and recloned it and then tried to ‘pod install’, but the terminal folder was in the trash or inbetween worlds so sadness ensued. ‘cd ..’ then ‘cd <repo name>’ sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a matter of choosing the default ruby to use. I had the default ruby shipped with Mac and a different one installed using a Ruby manager called rvm. So I made my rvm set the default ruby as the one it had installed.

This will list all paths where ruby is installed

```
which -a ruby
```

This will list all versions of ruby installed

```
rvm list
```

You should set the proper one you want to use as default

```
rvm use 3.0.2 --default
```

On a side note, you should be at a path in the shell where this works or else you would get this same error. I was trying a `pod` command in a project location that was in my desktop folder and it was failing. I had to change my directory in shell to desktop to set the default.