# Compass --version error

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass

When I run `compass --version` I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find sprockets-3.5.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:129:in `setup'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/AC-PCARDOSO-MAC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried to install the gem that is missing using:

```
rvm @global do gem install sprockets
```

And

```
gem install sprockets
```

Even then I still getting the same error.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall SASS and COMPASS already, but it didn't work.

*I am using El Captain

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972968/cant-install-gems-on-macos-x-el-capitan?s=3|3.0342

Comment: Thanks! This helped.