# Installing Compass (SCSS) - (Errno::EPERM) - OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, osx-elcapitan, compass

Im trying to install Compass on OS X El Capitan. 
I have Ruby installed `(ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15])` but when I use

```
sudo gem install compass
```

in terminal I have this result:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sass
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that apple has enabled ["System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) in El Capitan, so you can not write a file into `/usr/bin/` directory.

I solved this issue with https://rvm.io/ - just installed separate ruby version, then installed compass into it without sudo.

There is other possible solutions for this, check out this answer: [Can't install gems on OS X "El Capitan"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972968/cant-install-gems-on-macos-x-el-capitan#answer-32253142)