# Why wont SASS install on my mac?

Tags: macos, sass, rubygems, installation

I am trying to install SASS on my mac, and am having a lot of issues. So the first time it didn't work, I figured out that i had to run this command "xcode-select --install". That worked, and installed. But when I went to install SASS using "sudo gem install sass", It didnt work, and i got this error:

[image: SASS Install Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install gems on OS X "El Capitan"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972968/cant-install-gems-on-os-x-el-capitan)

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as your error message states, is that even sudo does not have access to `/usr/bin` in macOS's Rootless mode.  Try installing it in userland:

```
gem install sass --user-install
```